# how to prevent google chrome pop up user authentication box after failed

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

Well, maybe I didn't make my title very clearly. Here is the story:

I am developing a google chrome extension, which has an option page.

This extension will get some data from server by using HTTP basic authentication.

What I did is make ajax call with jQuery

```
$.ajax(
url: url,
method: 'GET',
beforeSend: // basic auth part
dataType: 'json'
success: // display information
error: // error message
);
```

But, currently if I input wrong username and password, chrome will continue pop up a authentication dialog box ask user input username and password, only if user cancel this dialog they can see the error message.

How can I prevent this dialog pop up, directly display the error message ask user input again within my extension page?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902411/avoid-http-auth-popup-in-a-chrome-extension-digest

Comment: Hey serg Thank you very much for providing this information. How I get the full picture in mind :-)