# How can I dismiss chrome "Authentication Required" popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to set username and password in "Authentication Required" popup via chrome extension.

Is there any chrome extension API so that I can get the popup and set my username/password on it?
or is there any way to dismiss that popup?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoid HTTP auth popup in a chrome extension (digest)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902411/avoid-http-auth-popup-in-a-chrome-extension-digest)

Answer (score 0):

The chrome.identity API may meet your needs (if your auth required is OAuth2).  If not, let me know what auth scheme you are using.

Comment: Could you provide an example to use chrome.identity to dismiss the "Authentication Required" popup?